# Akka and spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, akka

I am trying to combine akka with spring (without success). Basically it seems that somehow my application doesn't wont to read akka schema

Part of service-context.xml with schema:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:akka="http://akka.io/schema/akka"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://akka.io/schema/akka http://repo.akka.io/akka-1.3.1.xsd">
```

Next there are some beans and akka actor definition:

```
<akka:untyped-actor id="pushManager" autostart="false" implementation="com.myspace.messaging.PushManager"> </akka:untyped-actor>
```

While running server i receive message:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 55; columnNumber: 143; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://repo.akka.io/akka-1.3.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

And exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 55 in XML document from class path resource [service-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 55; columnNumber: 143; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'akka:untyped-actor'.
```

Schema is located under url: http://repo.akka.io/akka-1.3.1.xsd - I can easily open it inside web browser.

Any clue may help,
Thanks
Marek.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the following for the schemaLocation attribute in my spring beans XML:

http://akka.io/schema/akka http://akka.io/akka-1.3.1.xsd

If you notice in a browser that will cause a download prompt rather than rendering the result, so it may be more compatible with what Spring is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you move to the new version of Akka 2.2, the Spring integration package has been removed (you really don't need it). You should implement a UntypedActorFactory, a Creator function or an IndirectActorProducer.

See this blog post for more info; http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=272