# Akka constructor wiring via spring

Tags: java, spring, akka

I have read the links

[Akka and spring configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849254/akka-and-spring-configuration)

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/untyped-actors.html

Spring is no longer available as a module in Akka 2.4.1 but can be created and used as an extension. I also understand that the concept of bean/actor creation being managed by DI-fwk like Spring can cause fundamental conflicts with the Akka Actor parent-child/supervision model. So I still don't understand how to wire these together.

I have a set of actor classes and I have written them to be generic enough for example: properties like "listener", "name", "messageQueueName" etc are configurable. The link above tells me that I provide convenience factory constructors and then create actor with the code snippet

`system.actorOf(DemoActor.props(42), "demo");`

It is this line that I do not like. What I want to write in my `application.conf` is something like

```
deployment {
    /demo {
         magicNumber : 42
    }
}
```

and then in all my application I simply want to look up the actor (I am okay to use the actorSelection) method.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong path there, you should have a look at these tutorials:

- http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-java-spring
- https://myshittycode.com/2015/08/26/akka-spring-integration/

and for passing arguments via constructors check my answer to this question:

- [Custom Spring Bean Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975613/custom-spring-bean-parameters/36647912#36647912)

The configuration file is used for akka specific parameters (like specifying the dispatcher, mailbox, etc.)